# Javascript Scope in the context of onLoad vs. onReady

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I am new to javascript and want to understand what is going on with my code.  I am using jQuery and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) to do some web mapping.

Here is code example 1, where my map variable is created within the onReady function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var map = new.OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
    $.get(my_python.cgi_script which returns an html table of available layers)
    });
```

[As far as I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope), my 'map' variable has a local scope.

Within that function I add some layers, generate controls, etc.  All working and covered in the OpenLayers documentation.  I am also using jQuery's get method to call a python.cgi script which dynamically generates a table of available layers.  This all occurs within the above onReady.

I needed to work with the dynamically generated content and found that I needed to place my code into an onLoad function.  If I place the second codeblock into an onReady function the thumbnails are not accessible via jQuery because of the order in which things are rendered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var map = new.OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
    //More code to dynamically generate a list of available layers, stored in a table
    $.get(my_python.cgi_script which returns an html table of available layers)
    });

$(body).onLoad(function(){
 $(img.thumbnail).bind('click', function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('layer_name_id')
  var layer = new OpenLayers.WMS(//all the stuff to add the layer, including name)
  map.addLayer('layer') //map undefined due to scope
});
});
```

In the above block 'map' is undefined in the second variable.   I understand why (scope) and decided that map needed to be a global variable.  I then tried:

```
var map; //This is a global because it is defined outside of any functions?
$(document).ready(function(){
    map = new.OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
    //More code to dynamically generate a list of available layers, stored in a table
    $.get(my_python.cgi_script which returns an html table of available layers)
    });

$(body).onLoad(function(){
 $(img.thumbnail).bind('click', function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('layer_name_id')
  var layer = new OpenLayers.WMS(//all the stuff to add the layer, including name)
  map.addLayer('layer')
});
});
```

The map variable is still undefined.  Why?  Am I misunderstanding how a global works?

I was able to get everything working by putting the onLoad function inside of the onReady code block.  I am not sure why the below is working:

```
$(document).onReady(function(){
    var map = new.OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
    //More code to dynamically generate a list of available layers, stored in a table
    $.get(my_python.cgi_script which returns an html table of available layers)

$(body).onLoad(function(){
 $(img.thumbnail).bind('click', function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('layer_name_id')
  var layer = new OpenLayers.WMS(//all the stuff to add the layer, including name)
  map.addLayer('layer')
  });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code snippet where you declared global variable map is working. But Jquery has no method onReady and onLoad. Better create init() function that will be executed in $(document).ready() function dont mix $(document).ready and body.onload functions. Use init function and it document.ready event.

Comment: If I do that though won't my dynamically generated HTML not be accessible to jQuery?  The content (currently created in the ready function) may or may not exist when the functionality (coded in the onLoad function) is implemented.

Comment: It will be accessible why not. Use callbacks in ajax request.